# Restart forever.js for a node.js app through a cron?

Tags: node.js, bash, cron, forever

My node.js app crashes sometimes and sometimes forever.js automatically restarts it and sometimes it does not.

There's nothing in the logs - I run forever with '-e' option but that doesn't save any error log - my main log simply breaks off and that's it...

Tired of trying to figure it out I wonder if there's another solution: can I set up a cron, which would check my URL for 503 code and if it's the case, it would restart the app using forever?

I know how to white a bash script to start forever but how do I check if the URL returns 503 code?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not debug your app in the first place so it doesn't crash ? And I suggest you drop Forever and use your distro's default init system like systemd which can automatically restart processes if they exit unexpectedly.

Comment: Use the `curl` command if you want to test your app is responding properly to http.

Comment: @andré what's the advantage of systemd to forever?

Answer (score 0):

Start your app this way:

```
nohup forever app.js > logs &
```

Comment: @deemeetree it allows the command to continue in background after you've closed your terminal. But as I said before in my comments, using systemd is much more reliable and doesn't need manual intervention to start/restart the service if it were to crash.

Comment: Yes nohup does that. I've used nodejs with forever and always respected: Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms info. But if yours stays up ... just use that... but still debug your code first.

Comment: I actually realized that my provider was simply killing all processes so I guess forever would not restart the app because of that. So in that case - systemd would be the best choice right?

Comment: (They kill my processes because neo4j graph database is using too much memory and it's on a shared server for now)

Comment: @daniel , If i use nohup forever app.js > logs &  command i got a message in my terminal. Can you please explain what is issue in this. 

terminal@mymac : /var/www/node/chat$ nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout